# pyinstaller Uses Different Parent Path

Tags: python, pyinstaller

[image]

Hello amazing stack overflow folks, I want to ask you for some assistance in this issue. I have a Python script that needs several dependencies and python uses a different parent file path thus leading to an issue each time I convert .py to .exe using pyinstaller. I've attempted to remove the build directory and transfer the file from the dist directory to the location of the other dependencies but the problem continues.

Comment: did you check with absolute path ?

Comment: yes, sir @Nagakiran. I did it too, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: `pyinstaller --onefile -w 'filepath.py'`i hope you ran this command in cmd prompt, which is activated with referenced python environment and pyinstaller installation in specific enviroment

Comment: I have tried it too.

Comment: If you're using `--onefile`: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile) made my day.. (I used [Jonathon Reinhart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44352931/14278613))

Comment: please debug with `--onedir`.